# How to properly create instances containing a Map from a json file in dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a json file and create instances from it but whatever way I use, I end up stucked because of the *dynamic* type :

> type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, int>'

Here's my model :

```dart
class Race {
  final String name;
  final Map<String, int> abilitiesUpdater;

  const Race({
    required this.name,
    required this.abilitiesUpdater
  });

  static fromJson(json) => Race(name: json['name'], abilitiesUpdater: json['abilitiesUpdater']);
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to deserialize the json file :

```dart
class RacesApi {
  static Future<List<Race>> getRacesLocally(BuildContext context) async {
    final assetBundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
    final String fileContent = await assetBundle.loadString('Assets/COC_Monstres/Races.json');

    List<dynamic> parsedListJson = jsonDecode(fileContent);
    List<Race> racesList = List<Race>.from(parsedListJson.map<Race>((dynamic i) => Race.fromJson(i)));
    return racesList;
  }
}
```

Here's my json file :

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Vampire",
    "abilitiesUpdater": {
      "DEX": 2,
      "CHA": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Créature du lagon",
    "abilitiesUpdater": {
      "FOR": 2,
      "CON": 2
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

How can I properly cast this json object to fit into my class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :** To have something a little bit more handy and scalable, I created an extension, and it works fine eventhough I have to cast twice the object...

**My model :**

```dart
// import my extension

class Race {
  Race({
    required this.name,
    required this.abilitiesUpdater,
  });
  late final String name;
  late final Map<String, int> abilitiesUpdater;
  // late final AbilitiesUpdater abilitiesUpdater;

  Race.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    name = json['name'];
    abilitiesUpdater = (json['abilitiesUpdater'] as Map<String, dynamic>).parseToStringInt();
  }
}
```

**My extension :**

```dart
extension Casting on Map<String, dynamic> {
  Map<String, int> parseToStringInt() {
    final Map<String, int> map = {};

    forEach((key, value) {
      int? testInt = int.tryParse(value.toString());
      if (testInt != null) {
        map[key] = testInt;
      } else {
        debugPrint("$value can't be parsed to int");
      }
    });
    return map;
  }
}
```

Once again, any help on cleaning this is appreciated !

---

**Original answer :**

Thanks to [Sanket Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20630325/sanket-patel)'s answer, I ended up with a few changes that made my code works. However I'm pretty clueless on why I can't directly cast a

```dart
Map<String, dynamic>
```

object into a

```dart
Map<String, int>
```

one.
Any info on this would be appreciated :)

Here's how I changed my **model class** in the end :

```dart
class Race {
  Race({
    required this.name,
    required this.abilitiesUpdater,
  });
  late final String name;
  late final AbilitiesUpdater abilitiesUpdater;

  Race.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    name = json['name'];
    abilitiesUpdater = AbilitiesUpdater.fromJson(json['abilitiesUpdater']);
  }
}

class AbilitiesUpdater {

  final Map<String, int> abilitiesUpdater = {};

  AbilitiesUpdater.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    json.forEach((key, value) {
      abilitiesUpdater[key] = int.parse(value.toString());
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
class Race {
  final String name;
  // changed to dynamic
  final Map<String, dynamic> abilitiesUpdater;

  const Race({required this.name, required this.abilitiesUpdater});

  static fromJson(json) =>
      Race(name: json['name'], abilitiesUpdater: json['abilitiesUpdater']);
}
```

Maybe after get the object you can parse that `dynamic` into `int` if you need it.

Comment: It works but doesn't really solve the problem, it only ignores it :p
I'd like to avoid having to parse the values everytime I need them...
How comes that json doesn't fit my properly typed object ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Model Class to this:

```
class Race {
  Race({
    required this.name,
    required this.abilitiesUpdater,
  });
  late final String name;
  late final AbilitiesUpdater abilitiesUpdater;
  
  Race.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    name = json['name'];
    abilitiesUpdater = AbilitiesUpdater.fromJson(json['abilitiesUpdater']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['abilitiesUpdater'] = abilitiesUpdater.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class AbilitiesUpdater {
  AbilitiesUpdater({
    required this.FOR,
    required this.CON,
  });
  late final int FOR;
  late final int CON;
  
  AbilitiesUpdater.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    FOR = json['FOR'];
    CON = json['CON'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['FOR'] = FOR;
    _data['CON'] = CON;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer gave me  lead to find the apparent solution to my problem, thanks !
I wanted to keep my Map as flexible as possible and not to depend on its keys

Answer (score 0):

you can cast the json['abilitiesUpdater'] as Map<String, int> because internally flutter will set it default as Map<String, dynamic>

Code

```
class Race {
  final String name;
  final Map<String, int> abilitiesUpdater;

  const Race({
    required this.name,
    required this.abilitiesUpdater
  });

  static fromJson(json) => Race(name: json['name'], abilitiesUpdater: json['abilitiesUpdater']) as Map<String,int>;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it earlier but this doesn't solve my problem, I'm still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine with me i  tried it here is the link to the code https://dartpad.dev/?id=550918b56987552eb3d631ce8cb9e063.

If you still getting error you can try this

```
class Race {
  final String name;
  final Map<String, int> abilitiesUpdater;

   Race({
     required this.name,
     required this.abilitiesUpdater
  });

  static fromJson(json) => Race(name: json['name'], abilitiesUpdater: (json['abilitiesUpdater']as Map<String,int>)) ;
 }
```

or you can try this

```
  class Race {
final String name;
final Map<String, int> abilitiesUpdater;

const Race({required this.name, required this.abilitiesUpdater});

static fromJson(json) => Race(
      name: json['name'],
      abilitiesUpdater: json['abilitiesUpdater']
          .map((key, value) => MapEntry<String, int>(key, value as int)),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work either for me, I still get the same error.

Comment: @n3wbie checkout the answer i updated it try the last approach that might help you.

Comment: It doesn't work either, the message actually changed to `type '_Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, int>'`